# How to define static index, that deals with minimums, and polymorphic property?

Tags: ravendb

Ok, I have these POCO's

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class Offer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User Seller { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I have many classes that derive from Product, and product property of class Offer can be any one of them.

I would like to define static index that returns Offers with the lowest price for **each** Product, and then filter it by product type.

I got this far.

```
        Map = offers => offers.Select(x => new Offer { Product = x.Product, Price = x.Price });

        Reduce = results => from r in results
                            group r by r.Product into g
                            select new Offer { Product = g.Key , Price = g.Min(x => x.Price) };
```

This does work, and gives me the lowest prices, although i think Map should use only Product.Id, not the whole thing(I just don't know how to do it).

And when i query the index:

```
Session.Query<Offer>("BestOffersIndex").Where(offer => offer.Product is DerivedProduct)
```

it just ignores Where condition.

If I do this:

```
        Map = offers => offers.Select(x => new OfferIndexResult { ProductType = MetadataFor(x.Product)["Raven-Entity-Name"].ToString(), ProductId = x.Product.Id, Price = x.Price });

        Reduce = results => from r in results
                            group r by r.ProductId into g
                            select new OfferIndexResult { ProductType = g.FirstOrDefault().ProductType, ProductId = g.Key, Price = g.Min(x => x.Price) };

        TransformResults = (database, offers) => from offer in offers
                                                 let product = database.Load<Product>(offer.ProductId.ToString())
                                                 select new Offer { Product = product, Price = offer.Price };
```

Loaded product in live projection is null, and I don't know how to use ProductType for filtering purposes.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, I have a better understanding of the problem.  Specifically, the `Product` is *embedded* in the `Offer` class, and it is a base class of other products.  So, you can't use the approach I described (see edits), because you don't have access to the metadata of a `Product` when you are indexing an `Offer`.

The solution is to rely on the fact that your base class will be serialized with a `$type` attribute.  This is done by Json.Net because you are storing a class of a derived type.  A serialized `Offer` document would look like this:

```
{
  "SellerUserId": 1,
  "Product": {
    "$type": "YourNamespace.TheProductType, YourAssembly",
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "product name",
    "Manufacturer": "manufacturer"
  },
  "Price": 10.0
}
```

To be absolutely sure that the `$type` will always be there, mark the `Product` class as `abstract` so that all real products must be derived classes.

So when you are building your index map, you need access to this field.  You can get at it with the `AsDocument` method:

```
Map = offers => from offer in offers
                select new
                {
                    Product = offer.Product,
                    offer.Price,
                    ProductType = AsDocument(offer.Product)["$type"]
                };
```

When you go to query and want to filter by product type, you can get the string product type like this:

```
var productType = documentStore.Conventions.GetClrTypeName(typeof(ProductA));
```

I've put a full unit test together [here](https://gist.github.com/4557250) to show you how to use this technique to reach the goal you described.

Comment: I can't instantiate new Offer like this, because it doesn't have ProductType and ProductId properties. I can use some helper class that has these 3 properties, but how do I materialize Offer class with whole Product from it, in one go?

Comment: Just use an anonymous type.  That's what the map does anyway.  I updated the code example.

Comment: Could you expand your example with necessary reduce and/or live projection? I edited my question with route you propose, but I still can't achieve my goal.

Comment: Ok, will do.  Question - do you really need Product and User embedded in the Offer?  Or will UserId and ProductId be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: User is not necessary, but Product is.

Comment: I just tried your solution, but the results don't contain materialized Product, just its TypeName. And your tests pass, because you are just testing for price and id, and your first solution would also pass them.

Comment: If your goal is to return the product, that's easy, but then why reduce to lowest price?  You would lose that information in the result.  You would just be getting products by type name.

Comment: My goal is to return Products, with their lowest price

Comment: Just change what you're mapping.  Updated example.  See the updated GIST again.